# Probability inequality used in multi-armed bandit algorithm

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

I am following the proof for decaying $\epsilon$-greedy algorithm.

It used the inequality that

$$
\mathbb{P} \big[\bar{\mathbf{X}}_{i,T_i(n)}) \geq \bar{\mathbf{X}}^*_{T^*(n)}\big] \leq \mathbb{P}\big[\bar{\mathbf{X}}_{i,T_i(n)} \geq \mu_i + \frac{\Delta_i}{2}\Big] + \mathbb{P} \big[ \bar{\mathbf{X}}^*_{T^*(n)} \leq \mu^* - \frac{\Delta_i}{2}\Big]
$$

where  $ \bar{\mathbf{X}}_{i,n} =  \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\mathbf{X}_i$ and $T_i(n)$ is the number of times the arm $i$ has been played in the first $n$ steps. $\mu_i$ is the expected reward of the arm $i$ and $*$ in the superscript denotes the quantity associated with the optimal arm (the one with maximum reward) and $\Delta_i = \mu^* - \mu_i$

How can we derive the RHS of the inequality from the observation that   $\mathbb{P} \big[\bar{\mathbf{X}}_{i,T_i(n)}) \geq \bar{\mathbf{X}}^*_{T^*(n)}\big]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma.**
If $Y,Z,W$ are random variables on the same sample space, then
$$
\mathbb P(Y\geq Z)\leq \mathbb P(Y\geq W)+\mathbb P(Z\leq W).
$$
**Proof.**
If $Y<W$ and $W<Z$, then $Y<Z$, which means that
$$
\mathbb P(Y<Z)\geq \mathbb P(Y<W, W<Z).
$$
Taking complements of both sides and applying the union bound proves the lemma. $\square$

Now, recognize that the question is a special case of the lemma since
$$\mu_i+\frac{\Delta_i}{2}=\frac{\mu_i+\mu^*}{2}=\mu^*-\frac{\Delta_1}{2}.$$